# WPF Resize Image - Fixed with, sliding height

Tags: wpf, image, animation, resize

I have an image in WPF which I would like to enlarge to a fixed width (say 800px).
The image should stretch to this width using the original aspect ratio (so not as to distort) and the height should be scaled as necessary.

If the height is not too large for the container the top of the image should show at the top of the container. The image should then slide upwards until the bottom of the image reaches the bottom of the container via an animation (so at some point the whole image has been displayed).

Links or suggestions highly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried anything? And I guess you mean "slide downwards" instead of "slide upwards".

Comment: The first part is easy. Just use an `Image` control with a `Width` of 800, and a `Stretch` set to `Uniform` (which is the default value).